# Keep getting exception java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, struts2

I'm keep getting above mention error, I have included `spring-tx-4.0.2.jar` as previously asked questions.

**My `spring.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="dao" />

<jee:jndi-lookup id="depo" jndi-name="java:/depo"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="depo"/>


    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <!--    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <!--    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop> -->
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>

            <value>model.AtOrganisation</value>

        </list>
    </property>

</bean>


<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


<bean id="orgdao" class="dao.OrganisationDaoImp">
    <property name="sessionfactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="empAction" class="action.OraganisationAction">
    <property name="orgdao" ref="orgdao" />
</bean>
<bean id="empAction2" class="action.DevisionAction">
 
</bean>
```

**And My DAO class is this:**

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void addOrg(AtOrganisation org) {
 
    Session session = sessionfactory.openSession();

    session.saveOrUpdate(org);

}
```

I'm using spring 4.0.2 release and hibernate 4.2.8 and struts 2. Any one what cause this error?

**Jboss log :**

```
17:51:34,073 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) Failed to define class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor in Module "deployment.Depo5.war:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionInterceptor (Module "deployment.Depo5.war:main" from Service Module Loader)
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:428) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:261) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:76) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:548) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:189) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser$AopAutoProxyConfigurer.configureAutoProxyCreator(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:127) [spring-tx-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:84) [spring-tx-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187) [spring-beans-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125) [spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94) [spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) [spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) [spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454) [spring-context-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403) [spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) [spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106) [spring-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3777) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:792) [rt.jar:1.7.0_40]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:345) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.0.Final-redhat-2]
... 42 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cause of the error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/intercept/MethodInterceptor
```

this class is a part of *spring-aop* library or *aopaliance*, make sure you have deployed all required jars.

Comment: Solution is here.
http://javaprogrammingtips4u.blogspot.com/2010/04/resolve-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Comment: One thing to mention is that struts2 provide `aopalliance-1.0.jar` in the `lib` package.